# Swift NSTask How to Receive Output

Tags: swift, network-programming, packet-sniffers, packets

I currently have:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {



    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        var task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/sudo"
        task.arguments = ["tcpdump"]

        var pipe = NSPipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe

        var handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        handle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
        var observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification, object: handle, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (note: NSNotification!) -> Void in
            var dataRead = handle.availableData
            var str = NSString(data: dataRead, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("debug \(str)")
        })

        task.launch()
    }


    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

I have been looking for hours on this, and I can't find anything. Also, weirdly, sudo runs without requiring a password, but no packets are intercepted by tcpdump, hence I also need to know how to input a password. Thank you!

Comment: Check the tasks `terminationStatus` to see whether it ran at all. Also read the "sudo" man page (and in particular the "-A" option) to see how sudo reads the password.

Comment: I added `println(task.terminationStatus)` right below `println("debug \(str)")`, and it never prints....